# Populating dropdown by looping through an Array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/5m86J/6/

```
returnLOB =[
    {
        id: 1,
        name:"CIB"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name:"GTI"
    }
]
```

The Above is the array of objects.I need to populate the below dropdown with options from array.

```
<div id="LOBSelect" class="clearfix displayOnCreate">
    <span class="label">Dropdown</span>
    <select name="lob-select" class="dk" id="lobSelect"></select>
</div>
```

The following loop only produces a dropdown with option form object [GTI] not the first one.
Can anybody please tell me what is wrong here.

```
for (var j = 0; j < returnLOB.length; j++){
    $('#LOBSelect').find('select[name="lob-select"]').html($('<option/>', {
        value: returnLOB[j].name,
        text: returnLOB[j].name,
        id: returnLOB[j].id
    }));
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/bX8nK/

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted? OP shows code, a good explanation of the problem, provides a fiddle and shows the effort they made themselves. What more do you want downvoter?

Comment: In your loop you are (re)setting the html each time.  You need to create an option and then append it to the select

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! Yes i presumably had no good understanding of the difference between .html and .append- All answers much appreciated.

Comment: @Spdexter but that was the point of the question. Unfortunately the 'downvote all the things!' morons seem everywhere lately. Glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of `.html()`

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

*Code*

```
$('#LOBSelect').find('select[name="lob-select"]').append($('<option/>', {
    value: returnLOB[j].name,
    text: returnLOB[j].name,
    id: returnLOB[j].id
}));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/bX8nK/)

Comment: You've just improved my usage of `append`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/5m86J/7/

```
for (var j = 0; j < returnLOB.length; j++){
   $('#LOBSelect').find('select[name="lob-select"]').append($('<option/>', {
      value: returnLOB[j].name,
      text: returnLOB[j].name,
      id: returnLOB[j].id
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bX8nK/3/

```
var returnLOB = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "CIB"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "GTI"
}

]

$(returnLOB).each(function() {
    var lob = this;
    $('#LOBSelect select[name=lob-select]').append(
        $('<option/>', {
            value: lob.name,
            text: lob.name,
            id: lob.id
        })
    );
});
```

The .find() method which is called directly after the selector, could be made more efficient/readable by extending the selector itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < returnLOB .length; i++) {
                $("#lobSelect").append("<option id='"+returnLOB [i].Name+"' value='" + returnLOB [i].Name+ "'>" + result.results[i].Name + "</option>");
            }
```

Comment: This is probably the worst approach in terms of 'prone to error'.