# What is wrong with this dynamic dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new to ASP.Net MVC and Linq. I've been following online guides about how to fill a dropdownlist on selection of a value from another ddl.

I am getting the data from the database and filtering successfully but these results are not binding or displaying in the ddl.

I must be doing something basic wrong but for the life of me can't see what it is. Below is what I have so far. Help greatly appreciated.

My first drop down is filling correctly using an html helper - here is my second ddl in raw html

```
<select id="projectcode"></select>
```

Jquery in the script section of the same view

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.CustomerCode)").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("/IssueView/GetIssueList", { code: $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.CustomerCode)").val() },
                function (results) {
                    $("#projectcode").empty();
                    $.each(results, function (i, proj) {
                        $("#projectcode").append("" + proj.ProjectCode + "");
                    });
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller action

```
public ActionResult GetIssueList(string code)
{
    //dynamic fill of project code dropdown on selection of customer code drop down
    ProjectManager pm = new ProjectManager();

    var projectcodes = pm.SelectAllProjects();
    var test = projectcodes.Where(x => x.CustomerCode == code).ToList();
    return Json(test);
}
```

ProjectManager code

```
public List<Project> SelectAllProjects()
{
    using (IssueViewContext context = new IssueViewContext())
    {
        return context.Projects.ToList();
    }
}
```

I have debugged the variable test in the action which contains the filtered data. This proves the action is being invoked from the jquery script. But the ddl is not filled with this data - it is empty.

I'm also new to stack overflow so I hope I have provided all that is required. Thanks for reading

EDIT

I put an alert after the json return which wasn't invoked so it isn't getting past the json call.

I then changed the script to

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#projectcode").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.CustomerCode)").change(function () {
            if ($("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.CustomerCode)").val() != "Please select") {
                var options = {};
                options.url = "/IssueView/GetIssueList";
                options.type = "POST";
                options.data = JSON.stringify({ code: $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.CustomerCode)").val() });
                options.dataType = "json";
                options.contentType = "application/json";
                options.success = function (results) {
                    alert(results);
                    $("#projectcode").empty();                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        //var proj = (string).results[i].val;
                        $("#projectcode").append("<option>" + results[i] + "</option>");
                    }
                    $("#projectcode").prop("disabled", false);
                };
                options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving codes!"); };
                $.ajax(options);
            }
            else {
                $("#projectcode").empty();
                $("#projectcode").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I now get object [object Object] in the ddl. So a step closer but after searching I'm no nearer understanding how to parse the object?

Comment: `results` what do you have in it if you `console.log()` it.

Comment: Does your ddl display on your page at all? It sounds like a binding issue so take a look at where you render the page at. Could you post the code where you do this at? 

1) You need make the list (ddl)
2) Attach the list to the page
3) bind data to that list 
The code you have posted does not show where you attach the list  (or any HTML DOM Object you wish to display for that matter) to the page which is the problem you have described?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - lost now, I followed a guide in its entirety and presumed the binding was being done with jquery using the id.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674285/populating-dropdown-by-looping-through-an-array-of-objects/23674366#23674366

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$("#projectcode").append("" + proj.ProjectCode + "");
```

has to be like this:

```
$("#projectcode").append("<option>" + proj.ProjectCode + "</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

use kendoDropDownList like following :

```
<input id="ddlTest" value="0" />        

$.getJSON(URL)
                .done(function (results) {                   
                    $("#ddlTest").kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "Name",
                        dataValueField: "UserID",
                        dataSource: results ,
                        optionLabel: " ",
                        index: 0
                    });             
              );
             }
```